# Matching multiple <p> tags in scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I have something like the following `html`:

```
<div class="articleBody">
  <p>
    <strong>Text</strong> lorem ipsum... 
    <strong>lorem ipsum...</strong>
  </p>
  <p>lorem ipsum 
    <strong> lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</strong>
    lorem ipsum...lorem ipsum...lorem ipsum...lorem ipsum...
  </p>
</div>
```

In a more general way, I have a list of `<p>` tags with a few `<strong>` tags inside.

I would like to get the text of all the `<p>` tags, minus the `<strong>` tags... and by that, I mean just the text in the "articleBody" `div` class.

What I have is

```
response.xpath('string(//div[@class="articleBody"]//p)'.extract()
```

but that only returns the first `<p>`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about scrapy but you should be able to get all this text by using 
`//div[@class="articleBody"]/p/text()`

p.s I might have  misinterpreted what "minus the <strong> tags mean.

Comment: Luciddream is right, or //p instead of /p if you don't care if the p tag is a direct child of div[@class="articleBody"].   Could dump that all into a string like: ''.join(response.xpath('//div[@class="articleBody"]/p//text()').extract())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

give this a shot:

```
for node in response.xpath('//div[@class="articleBody"]//p'):
        print node.xpath('string()').extract()
```

...then you can concatenate your strings or add them to a list or whatever instead of just printing them like I did.

there is also the string-join() function for xpath 2.0 but it looks like scrapy supports xpath 1.0.

more info about string-join and such here: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join